# Most Recent Record using DateTime

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I am needing to select a single row that matches the user id and the one with the most recent creation date using codeigniter active records.

`creation_date` is a `datetime` field!

```
public function recent_invoice($user_id)
{
    $query = $this->CI->db->select('*');
    $query = $this->CI->db->from('invoices');
    $query = $this->CI->db->where('user_id', $user_id);
    $query = $this->CI->db->where('creation_date', )
    $query = $this->CI->db->get();

    $result = $query->row();
}
```

I want to get the rows that match the user id and then out of those get the most recent creation date. How do I do this? Thanks.

Comment: use the `order_by` on `creation_date` coloumn

Comment: Won't that still return more than one result?

Comment: add a limit 1 so that it will only return 1 dataset

Comment: Place that in an answer? As per Stackoverflows policy thank you.

Comment: check my answer, you can chain the methods. for cleaner code. test and tell me if it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, and if you don't need to get all columns, don't use `*`, use only the selected columns for added efficiency and also security.

```
 $query = $this->CI->db->select('*')
                       ->from('invoices')
                       ->where('user_id', $user_id)
                       ->order_by('creation_date')
                       ->limit(1)
                       ->get();
 $result = $query->row();
```

Comment: What about getting the invoice prior to the most recent?

Comment: @user3968645, that would be a different query but if you would like to use the same function just change the limit to 2 so it gets the latest and the next latest, and change the `row()` to `result` or `result_array()` and you can handle the return.